# Vertically centered image overlapping text

Tags: html, css, overlapping

I'm working on a website with a vertically centered image. There's a paragraph on the page also, and I want it to be below the image. I can't figure out to do this, and when the window is resized, the image overlaps the text. http://jsfiddle.net/qkmuM/ My CSS is

```
img {
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    max-width:900px;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **`display: absolute`**  from `img` tag   because the element is positioned relative to its body.

check [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/qkmuM/2/)

**Updates:** I think I got you point, placing the image in center and below the paragraph.  Now change it like

```
img {  // To vertically align the image
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table-cell;  
    max-width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
p {
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/qkmuM/5/)

Comment: Better to remove the useless `top`,`left`,... properties in this case, isn't it?

Comment: @HashemQolami right.  might has effect when OP has more items.  Now I have corrected it.

Comment: IMHO It is more appropriate, more semantic to use `display: block;` in the second approach. while `table-cell` doesn't have any special benefit here.

Comment: @HashemQolami here the OP mentioned about vertical-alignment.  so I have used `display: table-cell` as you know that `vertical-align` property can be used for `table-cell`

Comment: Exactly, but is it aligned vertically in the second fiddle? I see the image sticking at the top of the panel. However, I'm not the one should judge this :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set top position of paragraph.

```css
p {
  position:relative;
  top: Xpx    //(set it according to your requirement)
}
```